# Identifying memory leak in Swift GCD.async call

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, grand-central-dispatch, sqlite.swift

Some background about my app: I am drawing a map. When the user moves the map I perform a database query. I first do an rTree query to find the features that would be draw in the current viewport. Once I have those IDs I perform a second database query to extract the features (geojson) from the database. I do a quick check to see if the item already has been drawn, if not I do a `addChild` to render the feature on the map. I want to do these database looks up in the background via GCD so the user can move the map smoothly. I've implemented this but the memory usage quickly grows to 1gb, whereas if I do all the work in the main thread it uses around 250mb (acceptable for me). I'm assuming something is not being cleaned up because of the closure use. Any insight into the cause of the memory leak is appreciated.

```swift
public func drawItemsInBox(boundingBox: [Double]) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }

            var drawItems: [Int64] = []
            let table = Table("LNDARE_XS")
            let tableRTree = Table("LNDARE_XS_virtual")
            let coords = Expression<String?>("coords")
            let foid = Expression<String>("foid")
            let rTree = Expression<Int64>("rTree")
            let minX = Expression<Double>("minX")
            let maxX = Expression<Double>("maxX")
            let minY = Expression<Double>("minY")
            let maxY = Expression<Double>("maxY")
            let id = Expression<Int64>("id")

            // find all the features to draw via an rTree query
            for row in try! self.db.prepare(tableRTree.filter(maxX >= boundingBox[0] && minX <= boundingBox[1] && maxY >= boundingBox[2] && minY <= boundingBox[3])) {
                drawItems.append(row[id])
            }

            do {
                // get all the features geojson data
                let query = table.filter(drawItems.contains(rTree))
                for row in try self.db.prepare(query) {

                    // skip drawing if the feature already exists on the map
                    if self.featureTracking["LNDARE_XS"]?[Int64(row[foid])!] == nil {

                        // convert the database string to an array of coords
                        var toBeRendered:[CGPoint] = []
                        let coordsArray = row[coords]!.components(separatedBy: ",")

                        for i in 0...(coordsArray.count / 2) - 1 {
                            toBeRendered.append(CGPoint(x: (Double(coordsArray[i*2])!), y: (Double(coordsArray[(i*2)+1])!)))
                        }

                        let linearShapeNode = SKShapeNode(points: &toBeRendered, count: toBeRendered.count)
                        linearShapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
                        linearShapeNode.lineWidth = 0
                        linearShapeNode.fillColor = NSColor.black

                        // append the featureId for tracking and call addChild to draw
                        self.scaleLayer.addChild(linearShapeNode)
                        self.featureTracking["LNDARE_XS"]?[Int64(row[foid])!] = linearShapeNode
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                // catch
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try using an autorelease pool

Answer (score 1):

Maybe change `toBeRendered` can save some:

```
  var toBeRendered:[CGPoint] = []
            for row in try self.db.prepare(query) {

                // skip drawing if the feature already exists on the map
                if self.featureTracking["LNDARE_XS"]?[Int64(row[foid])!] == nil {

                    // convert the database string to an array of coords
                    toBeRendered.removeAll()
                    let coordsArray = row[coords]!.components(separatedBy: ",")

                    for i in 0...(coordsArray.count / 2) - 1 {
                        toBeRendered.append(CGPoint(x: (Double(coordsArray[i*2])!), y: (Double(coordsArray[(i*2)+1])!)))
                    }
```

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of moving the variable into a different scope? Are you saying its creating a strong reference resulting in a memory leak or is it a general performance enhancement?

Comment: Toberendered.append() is an time consuming operation. So you may optimize this array by init once and reuse it so you don’t need to wait auto release which may come later. Also you can add a reservecapcity command after init, which can alloc a block region for your variable which can speed up 30% faster .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using an auto release pool since you are not on the main thread

```
public func drawItemsInBox(boundingBox: [Double]) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else {
            return
        }

        var drawItems: [Int64] = []
        let table = Table("LNDARE_XS")
        let tableRTree = Table("LNDARE_XS_virtual")
        let coords = Expression<String?>("coords")
        let foid = Expression<String>("foid")
        let rTree = Expression<Int64>("rTree")
        let minX = Expression<Double>("minX")
        let maxX = Expression<Double>("maxX")
        let minY = Expression<Double>("minY")
        let maxY = Expression<Double>("maxY")
        let id = Expression<Int64>("id")

        // find all the features to draw via an rTree query
        for row in try! self.db.prepare(tableRTree.filter(maxX >= boundingBox[0] && minX <= boundingBox[1] && maxY >= boundingBox[2] && minY <= boundingBox[3])) {
            drawItems.append(row[id])
        }

        do {
            // get all the features geojson data
            let query = table.filter(drawItems.contains(rTree))
            for row in try self.db.prepare(query) {
                autoreleasepool{
                    // skip drawing if the feature already exists on the map
                    if self.featureTracking["LNDARE_XS"]?[Int64(row[foid])!] == nil {

                        // convert the database string to an array of coords
                        var toBeRendered:[CGPoint] = []
                        let coordsArray = row[coords]!.components(separatedBy: ",")

                        for i in 0...(coordsArray.count / 2) - 1 {
                        toBeRendered.append(CGPoint(x: (Double(coordsArray[i*2])!), y: (Double(coordsArray[(i*2)+1])!)))
                        }

                        let linearShapeNode = SKShapeNode(points: &toBeRendered, count: toBeRendered.count)
                        linearShapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
                        linearShapeNode.lineWidth = 0
                        linearShapeNode.fillColor = NSColor.black

                        // append the featureId for tracking and call addChild to draw
                        self.scaleLayer.addChild(linearShapeNode)
                        self.featureTracking["LNDARE_XS"]?[Int64(row[foid])!] = linearShapeNode
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            // catch
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No impact unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion.